# EGPU compatibility with Mac?

Tags: gpu, osx, hardware

Due to certain software limitations, I need to use a Mac for Blender. With recent updates allowing for GPU Cycles rendering on Mac, are external GPU's a viable alternative to a PC build in performance? Are they compatible? I've always used PC and haven't followed Mac or Blender's compatibility with Mac super closely, but I've heard hopeful things regarding their integration. Looking at the benchmarks for the M1 Ultra, I don't foresee it being a viable option for what we need unless external hardware was able to be used.

For context, all other systems and software in our network are Mac and having a different computer would add security and software issues, hence why our IT guys are pushing for a Mac if it is an option. Our other idea is utilizing Flamenco on a Mac and having an essentially offline PC for rendering.

Comment: +1 for Flamenco 